# How to correct HTML text wrapping

Tags: html, coldfusion, word-wrap

This is a basic html text wrapping problem but it has me stumped. I'm using coldfusion on the back end. I have the following template:

```
 This line has 30 characters it
 This line has 40 characters it a b a b a
 This line has 50 characters it a b a b a as d f e
 This line has 60 characters it a b a b a as d f e we r t yy 
 This line has 70 characters it a b a b a as d f e we r t yy e 4 r t 5
```

I load the template into a textarea to let the user edit it to make a report as follows:

```
 <textarea name="Report" cols="72" rows="40">#template#</textarea>
```

Then i add pre/pre to preserve any of their added punctuation:

```
 <CFSET #Report# = "<pre>" &   #Report#   & "</pre>" >
```

Then i save the Report in a sql db as a text variable.
But when i try to retrieve the Report and output with wrapping set to 72,

```
 <CFSET #Report# = #wrap(#Report#, 72)#>
```

I get this weird spacing that i cant figure out:

```
 This line has 30 characters it
 This line has 40 characters it a b
 a b a
 This line has 50 characters it a b a b a as d f e
 This line has
 60 characters it a b a b a as d f e we r t yy 
 This line has 70
 characters it a b a b a as d f e we r t yy e 4 r t 5
```

I've wracked my brain with this and any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never really used `Wrap()` but it looks like, in ACF, it just inserts a break every 72 characters (Railo seems to pay attention to placement).

You have a few options.

The easiest to work with solution is to dipsplay your data with a replace like this.

```
#REReplace(variable,"(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)","<br>\1","ALL")#.
```

Or `#ParagraphFormat(variable)#` may be up your ally.

You won't need a PRE wrapper in these cases, though you could use a css to set a monospaced font if that's why you're using pre. Since it's not in PRE, your content will obey the parameters of its container (though you may need to set a width for the container.

Something else that might work, if you're determined to keep the effect is this, but be warned that it makes no account for tags. While the design does take account for find a space or newline, if you have some text like `<input type="`, and input happens to cross the threshold, you'll end up with a break at the space.

```
#rereplace(variable,"([^\n]{1,71})[\s]","\1<br>","ALL")#

<cfsavecontent variable="seventytwo">abcdefghijklmnopqrstabcdefghijklmnopqrstabcdefghijklmnopqrst
 This line has 30 characters it
 This line has 40 characters it a b a b a
 This line has 50 characters it a b a b a as d f e
 This line has 60 characters it a b a b a as d f e we r t yy 
 This line has 70 characters it a b a b a as d f e we r t yy e 4 r t 5 
</cfsavecontent>

<pre><cfoutput>#wrap(seventytwo,72)#

#rereplace(seventytwo,"([^\n]{1,71})[\s]","\1<br>","ALL")#</cfoutput></pre>

<cfsavecontent variable="seventytwo">
Contrary to popular belief,
  Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</cfsavecontent>

<pre><cfoutput>#rereplace(seventytwo,"([^\n]{1,71})[\s]","\1<br>","ALL")#</cfoutput></pre>
```

Edit: The above does not account for 72+ character strings without spaces. You can use something like this for that.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="seventytwo">
Contrary to popular belief,
  Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. cookiesarethebestbuttheycanmakeyoufatandnoonelikesbeingcalledfatsodonteatlotsofcookies It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</cfsavecontent>

<pre><cfoutput>#rereplace(seventytwo,"(([^\n]{1,71})[\n ]|([^\n]{1,71}))","\1<br>","ALL")#</cfoutput></pre>
```